# Can't set a property

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on an implementation of the genetic algorithm to solve an advanced Traveling Salesman Problem (with edges depending on daytime to simulate traffic hours). It's working out quite well so far.

I've got some classes `Inhabitant` which has a `GeneticString`, a `Population` and some others classes.
In each iteration, where the generation of the simulation advances there is a chance of mutation, so to be safe I want to save the best of all my Inhabitants (Solutions/Tours) in case this one mutates and I'll never find a better one.

So `Population` has a `best` property and after each iteration I call `determineBest()`to see if the best inhabitant of my current population (I keep the population sorted, so the inhabitant with key 0 is the best) is better than the one I remembered with `best`

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self,p,simulation):
        self.inhabitants = []
        self.generation = 0
        self.simulation = simulation
        self.map = self.simulation.map
        for i in range(0,p):
            self.addRandomInhabitant()

        self.best = self.inhabitants[0] 
...
    def setBest(self,b):
        self.best = Inhabitant(b.locations(),self)

    def determineBest(self):
        if (self.inhabitants[0].fitness() < self.best.fitness()):
            # WHY!?
            print "overwriting " + str(self.best.fitness()) + " with "+ str(self.inhabitants[0].fitness())
            self.setBest(self.inhabitants[0])
```

"This can't be so hard" but I'm doing something wrong. The best Inhabitant is never saved.

The output of the debug print is (for the last generations):

```
overwriting 3.57107095019 with 3.55664843948
overwriting 3.63240015308 with 3.55664843948
overwriting 3.57107095019 with 3.55664843948
```

Since my implementation depends on the current time and the fitness value of a Tour changes with the given starting time, I've already checked on this. For each fitness value calculation the same starting time is used.

If you need access to the full code, I could host it on a git-hoster.

Comment: Why do you create a new inhabitant when you want to "set the best"? Isn't self.inhabitants[0] already an inhabitant?

Comment: yes it is. I did it because I thought I'd just set a reference or something like that. I'm a python beginner, so I went safe by creating a new Inhabtiant.

Comment: use @property decorators above a function called "def best(self, score):".  Sounds like your setBest is a setter and your determineBest is the getter.

Comment: In `setBest`, put this line of code: `print b.fitness(), self.best.fitness()`. If you put it below `self.best = ...`, you'll probably get two different values

Comment: @Back2Basics yeah sorry for the naming confusion

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini No it prints exactly the same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that mutating the inhabitant actually mutates some attribute that is shared with the copy, probably the object returned by Inhabitant.locations(). In this case, mutating the original inhabitant will also mutate the copy. You would need to create a copy of the object returned by locations() or (to be on the safe side) change the locations() method itself to return a copy.

Comment: This is exactly, what the problem was. A new instance of Inhabitant doesn't solve the problem if the use the same list of locations, which will be mutated.

Answer (score 0):

```
(self.inhabitants[0].fitness() < self.best.fitness())
```

Hi,

If you want to maximize fitness, should you not change the "<" to ">"?

Comment: Sorry, this is a misunderstanding. The fitness value ist the duration of the tour, so a lower value would be better.